# How to get the name of the table that was changed in sqlite?

Tags: triggers, sqlite

Does anyone here knows how to get the name 
of the table that was changed,updated or deleted
in SQLite?..i found the function changes() and totalChanges()
but they only return the number of database rows that were 
changed or inserted or deleted by the most recently completed SQL statement.

Comment: how do you create your triggers ? The trigger is attached to only ONE table, so why not create it including the name while creating (a const 'NAMEOFMYTABLE') ?

Answer (score 0):

In most RDBMS's you have some kind of journaling that captures all database transactions for data backup and recovery. In Oracle, it's called a redo log. That is where you would go to check if a table name has changed.

But I'm not familiar enough with SqlLite to know if this is available. I did find a thread where a similar question was asked,  and it was recommended to implement it yourself. [Try reading through the this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/67142) and see if this satisfies your requirements:

But aside from all of that, I would also recommend that your app use views, that way you protect the model from changes.